# How to add extra letters coming out from serialized string in php?

Tags: php, string, serialization

I am working on a serialized string in php in which I want to add additional letters when its unserialized.

The snippets of serialized string is:

```
a: 7: {
    s: 3: "mon";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "tue";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "wed";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "thu";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "fri";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "sat";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
    s: 3: "sun";a: 2: {
        s: 5: "start";s: 5: "09:00";s: 3: "end";s: 5: "21:00";
    }
}
```

The php code which I have used in order to make the above serialized string unserialized is:

```
<?php 
   $serialized = '';
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['item']->logistic_out); $i++) {
   if(strcmp($data['item']->logistic_out[$i]->logistics_type, "location_pickup") == 0)
   {
   $serialized .= strtolower($data['item']->logistic_out[$i]->logistics_times);
   }
   }
   if($serialized != '')
   {
   /*
   echo '<span class="font-weight-bold how-can-this-text">' . "how can this item be received" . '</span>';
   echo "<br>"; 
   echo "<br>"; 
   echo '<span class="font-weight-bold mb-3 ml-3">' . "pickup from item's location <br/>" . '</span>';
   echo "<br>";
   echo "<br>";  */
   $unserialized = unserialize( $serialized );

   foreach($unserialized as $key=>$value)
   {
   echo $key.":&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;".$value['start']."&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;".$value['end']."<br/> <br/>";
   }
   }
   else
   {
       echo "<p style=\"font-style: italic;\">No information available</p>";
   }
   ?>
```

**Problem Statement:**

The echo statement in the above code is generating the following o/p. I am wondering what changes I should make in the **echo statement above so that the o/ps has Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert to a timestamp and then extract the full textual representation of the day of the week:

```
echo date('l', strtotime($key));
```

To change the time from 24 to 12 hour do the same sort of thing:

```
echo date('g', strtotime($value['end']));
```

See [PHP - date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for all of the formats.

Comment: Can you give me a pointer how can we do that ? I haven't worked on php that much.

Comment: I have a similar question.  The current code which I am working on pulls the time in 24 hours format. Is there any we can day that in 12hour format ? In the screenshot, instead of 21, it should be 9.

Comment: Where do I need to add this `echo date('g', strtotime($key));` ?

Comment: I think the `.$value['end'].` is pulling the 24 hour format.

Comment: At this moment, I am using this   `echo date('l', strtotime($key)).":&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;".$value['start']."&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;".$value['end']."<br/> <br/>";`

Comment: The above code is giving me the following o/p:  

`Monday:             06:00             21:00` .  Just a snippet

Comment: Typo, use `$value['end']`

Comment: Ok, how can we use here `echo date('l', strtotime($key)).":&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;".$value['start']."&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;".$value['end']."<br/> <br/>";` ?

Answer (score -2):

Updated my answer. Please check

```
echo date('l', strtotime($key)).":&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;".$value['start']."&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;".$value['end']."<br/> <br/>";
```

Comment: Sunday won't be in double quotes at last ? Sorry I didn't work on php much so not sure.

Comment: Where do you want me to add that array ? It doesn't seems to work.

Comment: next to $serialized=""; is good for performance. edited the code accordingly

Comment: edited my answer. please check it by just changing that line